# Why event flag related functions does not work correctly outside of tasks in keil rtx?

Tags: rtos, keil, rtx

As you know event flags are very useful (e.g. let task running),but unfortunately their control functions (os_evt_clr/set/wait) does not work outside of tasks bodies correctly(e.g. in interrupt handling functions). For alternative i used a variable ,I initialized it in Interrupt handler when needed ,then used it on another task to running a os_evt_set() function for let MCU entering a task.

```
    bool Instance_Variable;

    Interrupt_Handler()
    {
    if(xxxx)
    Instance_Variable=1
    }
//--------------------------        
    Secondary_Task()
    {
    //This is frequently run task
    if(Instance_Variable==1)
    {
    os_evt_set (0x0001, Primary_Task_ID);
    Instance_Variable=0;
    }
    }
//--------------------------    
    Primary_Task()
    {
    Result = os_evt_wait_or (0x0001, 0xFFFF);
    //Task's body 
    os_evt_clr (0x0001, Primary_Task_ID);
    }
```

Any better approach?WBR.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use function prefixed with os_ inside ISR. Usage hints from RTX documentation:

- Functions that begin with os_ can be called from a task, but not from an interrupt service routine.
- Functions that begin with isr_ can be called from an IRQ interrupt service routine but not from a task.

This code will work:

```
Interrupt_Handler() {
    if(xxxx) {
         isr_evt_set (0x0001, Primary_Task_ID);
    }
}
//--------------------------        
Primary_Task() {
    Result = os_evt_wait_or (0x0001, 0xFFFF);
    //Task's body 
    os_evt_clr (0x0001, Primary_Task_ID);
}
```